# How to change the TrackBar control actions when keyboard keys are pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

The `TrackBar` control changes in the opposite direction to the one it is supposed to when being changed by:
page-up / page-down / arrow-up / arrow-down.

This is mentioned in details here:
[Why does the Trackbar value decrease on arrow up/PgUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831694/why-does-the-trackbar-value-decrease-on-arrow-up-pgup)

Is there a way to fix/reverse this behavior ?

Comment: Pretty good way to fatally confuse the user with a control that works exactly opposite from every other trackbar used in any other program on his machine.  Set the Orientation property to Vertical to make it unambiguous.  If you insist on changing it then you need to derive your own control from the TrackBar class and override its ProcessCmdKey() method.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I will see this function, .. I have already received negative feedback from users of how the trackbar functions, it is the opposite of many of the famous application or what the user expects.

Answer (score 2):

Huh...I never noticed that before.  Here's my stab at the suggestion by @Hans:

```
public class MyTrackBar : TrackBar
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                this.Value = Math.Min(this.Value + this.SmallChange, this.Maximum);
                return true;

            case Keys.Down:
                this.Value = Math.Max(this.Value - this.SmallChange, this.Minimum);
                return true;

            case Keys.PageUp:
                this.Value = Math.Min(this.Value + this.LargeChange, this.Maximum);
                return true;

            case Keys.PageDown:
                this.Value = Math.Max(this.Value - this.LargeChange, this.Minimum);
                return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Idle_Mind's answer is good and helped me actually, but it has one downside, that is, it prevents the control from raising the `Scroll` and `ValueChanged` events when <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, or <kbd>PageDown</kbd> is clicked. So, here's my version:

```
public class ProperTrackBar : TrackBar
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        int oldValue = this.Value;
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                this.Value = Math.Min(this.Value + this.SmallChange, this.Maximum);
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                this.Value = Math.Max(this.Value - this.SmallChange, this.Minimum);
                break;
            case Keys.PageUp:
                this.Value = Math.Min(this.Value + this.LargeChange, this.Maximum);
                break;
            case Keys.PageDown:
                this.Value = Math.Max(this.Value - this.LargeChange, this.Minimum);
                break;
            default:
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }

        if (Value != oldValue)
        {
            OnScroll(EventArgs.Empty);
            OnValueChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```